# How to call Mailchimp API method in PHP

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm using `mailchimp` API v2 for send campaign.  Below is my code for `send` function but it say's function is undefined.

```
include('lib/Mailchimp.php');
    $MailChimp = new Mailchimp('755d575xxxxxxxx4d881-us8');

    try{
    $aa = $MailChimp->send('mailchimxxxxxx7ca1ff1d2.04256b3fa1');  
    }
    catch (Exception $e){};
```

below API function is used.
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/send.php

How should I correctly call that `send` function?

var_dump($Mailchimp);

```
object(Mailchimp)#243 (18) { ["apikey"]=> string(36) "755d5752cxxxxxx881-us8" ["ch"]=> resource(162) of type (curl) ["root"]=> string(34) "https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/" ["debug"]=> bool(false) ["folders"]=> object(Mailchimp_Folders)#242 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["templates"]=> object(Mailchimp_Templates)#244 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["users"]=> object(Mailchimp_Users)#245 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["helper"]=> object(Mailchimp_Helper)#246 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["mobile"]=> object(Mailchimp_Mobile)#247 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["conversations"]=> object(Mailchimp_Conversations)#248 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["ecomm"]=> object(Mailchimp_Ecomm)#249 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["neapolitan"]=> object(Mailchimp_Neapolitan)#250 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["lists"]=> object(Mailchimp_Lists)#251 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["campaigns"]=> object(Mailchimp_Campaigns)#252 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["vip"]=> object(Mailchimp_Vip)#253 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["reports"]=> object(Mailchimp_Reports)#254 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["gallery"]=> object(Mailchimp_Gallery)#255 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } ["goal"]=> object(Mailchimp_Goal)#256 (1) { ["master"]=> *RECURSION* } }
```

Comment: can you change  $MailChimp = new MailChimp('755d575xxxxxxxx4d881-us8'); to  $MailChimp = new Mailchimp('755d575xxxxxxxx4d881-us8');

Comment: check and print object $MailChimp may be 

`include('lib/Mailchimp.php'); `

is not including try with this

Comment: Does your Object get initiated? `var_dump($MailChimp)`  produces something?

Comment: @Satya Thanks, I've change that (mistake) but nothing happen.

Comment: can you add this line to your catch block : var_dump($e); and see the output

Comment: @sismaster it prints some objects array

Comment: @stUrb it prints some objects array.

Comment: @Satya nothing happen for catch block.

Comment: paste the output of var_dump($aa); please

Comment: Sorry var_dump($aa); is Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mailchimp::send(). paste `var_dump($Mailchimp);` top.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the PHP wrapper that Mailchimp provides which is tricky since is doesn't match their API reference exactly. The campaign send method is found under the campaign class. (V2.x instantiates this sub class in 'src/Mailchimp.php'). Sending a campaign would look like this:

```
<?php
include_once('mailchimp/src/Mailchimp.php');

try {
    //Connect to Mailchimp using your API Key
    $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp('c82620103cf2***********-us11'); 
} 
catch (Mailchimp_Error $e) {
    echo('Error opening new mailchimp instance'.$e);
}

//Call this to return an array of campaigns from your MC account
$cList=$Mailchimp->campaigns->getList();

//Returned $id is something  like 'aer2dfcd18'
$id=$cList['data'][0]['id'];

//Send out the campaign
$Mailchimp->campaigns->send($id);

?>
```

There are some other improvements you could make here like using a try-catch for every method call or searching for the campaign by name instead of indexing but I wanted to keep the example simple. I hope this helps you and future MC developers!